# how to create a text menu and text only sub menu?

Tags: html, text, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop down menu for my website at http://jackcrane.co.uk

I want to create a drop down text only menu to appear under Health & Fitness and Gaming text, currently I have been trying to fiddle around with some code here - http://jsfiddle.net/VCX7T/6/ (css is on the jsfiddle site)

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>Parent 1
        <ul>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Parent 2
        <ul>
            <li>Child 4</li>
            <li>Child 5</li>
            <li>Child 6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but cant get it to drop down below where I would need it on my site, is anyone able to help? Thanks

Comment: You didn't explain the problem. What are you trying to achieve ? for example: onhover show sub-menu ?

Comment: Do you want the menu to be like on your site or like on the fiddle? On your site you've used basic inline links but on the fiddle it's a list - there's quite a difference.

Comment: Were you searching for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VCX7T/227/

Comment: @RononDex Ye thats it, but can I get it so it doesnt have the black border around it?

Comment: @user3095495 I have posted you a new fiddle in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle with a dropdown menu. I changed the following code:

```
/* This part makes the top-level menu horizontal instead of vertical */
nav ul li {
    display:inline;
}

/* This part positions the submenus */
nav > ul > li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VCX7T/231/

Comment: When i go to click on a link the text disappears before I am able to click the link, is there a way round this? Thank you for your help so far!!!

Comment: Yes. I have replace `top: 30px` with `padding-top: 30px;` http://jsfiddle.net/VCX7T/231/

Comment: @user3095495 Eddited answer again with new fiddle which should work now ;)